# File parser (C++) - enum variables to xml/json file - is there any already made, or should I write one

Tags: c++, parsing, enums

As a part of bigger program I need a program (C++ language) that will parse the header file. 
It should create xml/json file with only enum variables from passed header file. It would be great if it will support problematic enums like:

```
enum{
var1 = core::SOME_VAR,
var2,
var3
}enumName;
```

where core class/struct can be in included file which is in another folder.
But, to simplify the problem, it can simply ignore problematic enums.

I don't want to write such parser by myslef until it won't be really necessary. So I started to look for one in internet. I found http://gccxml.github.io/ - I could work with that, but:

1. If there is any inlcuded file that he can't read (e.g. because it's in another folder), or any other 'compilation' problem then it don't give any output file. I tried to set some flags in this program so it give any output, but it didn't work.
2. It generates sooo much unnecessary xml code...

I didn't found any other program that would suit me.
So my questions: If You know that parser that I mentioned earlier - is there any way to set it so it will match my needs? Or maybe You could point me any good parser for that problem? Or I should write one by myself